# mejor proceso y bucle en Ruby con un random

Tags: ruby

Necesito guardar un numero random dentro de un ciclo variable de un total indeterminado de una lista, tengo como parámetros de entrada, el total de la lista y el ciclo.
Este es el código que programé y se que es sobre elaborado, y ese es el punto, quiero optimizarlo.

```
puts 'KABUUM!!!'
total = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclo = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclos = total / ciclo
resto = total % ciclo
c = 0
z = ciclo * ciclos + 1
for x in 1..ciclos do
linea = ''
  for y in 1..ciclo do
   r = rand(100..999)
   linea << ',' if linea != ''
   linea << r.to_s
  end
  puts linea
  end
if resto > 0  
  linea = ''
  for n in z..total do
   r = rand(100..999)
   linea << ',' if linea != ''
   linea << r.to_s
  end
  puts linea
end
```

esta es una muestra de tres salidas:

```
D:\Sites\ruby>
D:\Sites\ruby>ruby ciclo.rb
KABUUM!!!
25
5
410,457,482,924,302
575,411,616,708,597
558,507,508,349,594
427,536,920,915,941
726,910,492,558,176

D:\Sites\ruby>ruby ciclo.rb
KABUUM!!!
24
5
635,194,107,247,770
814,435,570,986,554
602,225,357,117,144
594,292,960,814,602
488,412,571,990

D:\Sites\ruby>ruby ciclo.rb
KABUUM!!!
26
5
245,141,736,288,941
221,687,762,562,377
447,577,304,316,641
184,384,439,307,420
407,664,726,875,752
287

D:\Sites\ruby>
```

el amigo @gerry me ayudó con un código que funciona perfecto para números consecutivos, pero no sé como agregarle el random a este código:

```
puts 'KABUUM!!!'
total = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclo = gets.chomp.to_i
(1..total).each_slice(ciclo) do |linea|
  puts linea.join(",")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el mismo código que te proporcioné pero generando el *random* antes de convertir el arreglo `linea` a un *string*, y esto lo puedes generar con el método [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-map); por ejemplo:

```
puts 'KABUUM!!!'

total = gets.chomp.to_i
ciclo = gets.chomp.to_i

(1..total).each_slice(ciclo) do |linea|
  puts linea.map { |_| rand(100..999) }.join(",")
end
```

- `map` ejecuta el código proporcionado en el bloque por cada elemento (disponible en la variable `_`) de la colección y te devuelve un arreglo con el resultado.
- La variable `_` toma ese nombre ya que en tu bloque **no** se está utilizando, sin embargo necesitas especificarla ya que `map` siempre te dará la variable; la comunidad de *Ruby* recomienda llamar esas variables que no se utilizan con `_` para identificarlas, aunque podrías ponerle el nombre que quieras.